# React - Handle clicking a button to display some text

Tags: reactjs, button, mapping, display, handle

I map buttons and need them to display text once clicked. I use an ID state to grab which key was clicked and then the classname should display that text, and should only display one description at a time.
Here's my code for the component:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const items = [
  {
    name: 'Pizza',
    description: 'Cheese, bread, red sauce',
    price: '4.99',
    key: 0,
  },
  {
    name: 'Spaghetti',
    description: 'cooked noodles, red sauce, parmesan',
    price: '3.99',
    key: 1,
  },
  { name: 'Soda', description: 'pepsi products', price: '4.99', key: 2 },
];

const MenuItem = () => {
  const [ID, setID] = useState(null);

  const itemHandler = (item) => {
    console.log(item);
    if (ID === null) {
      setID(item.key);
    } else {
      setID(null);
    }
    console.log(ID);
  };

  return (
    <li className="items">
      {items.map((item) => {
        return (
          <ul key={item.key}>
            <button className="menu-item" onClick={itemHandler}>
              {`${item.name}          ${item.price}`}
            </button>
            <h4
              className={`menu-description ${
                ID === item.key ? 'active-item' : 'none'
              }`}
            >
              {item.description}
            </h4>
          </ul>
        );
      })}
    </li>
  );
};

export default MenuItem;
```

When I console.log(item) I get the event (clicking the button) instead of item from the items array. Not sure what I can do to fix.

Comment: Just pass the item to the `itemHandler` directly: `onClick={() => itemHandler(item)}`. Also, you're using`<ul>` and `<li>` backwards -- `<ul>` is the list, `<li>` is the item.

Comment: You're a saint, thank you!